# How to deal with a "optional" circular reference

Tags: database-design

I'm having trouble with a problem about circular references.I'm not managing to find a good design solution.

We have a legacy system of scheduling.

Users

- userId

TimeSlot (Availability)

- timeSlotID
- start_hour
- finish_hour
- FK_userID

Appointments

- timeSlotID_FK
- Details
- start_hour
- finish_hour

That way we have a Chain 
User - (1,n) -> Availability - (1, n) -> Appointments

Now what I want to do is schedule appointments in an extraordinary time-slot. (A user appears when he should not be available and wants to make an appointment.

That way I need to shortcut the Availability.

User -> Appointment

But if I add a new field UserFK I feel I'll create a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my observations on the database design, based on your question.

- Disassociate FK_UserID from Timeslot. Make them separate entity. YOu
  will have the flexibility to associate an user to appointment. YOu
  can have a separate table `User_Timeslot`, if you want to maintain the
  availability of user in general. It can be used to check the
  availability and should not affect, if the user comes to make
  appointment.
- Now, `appointment` will be a bridge table, which maps user, timeslot
  and corresponding appointment. You can also have a flag IsUserAdhocAppointment, which will tell whether the user appeared outside his timeslot(based on the `User_Timeslot` table). The appointment is for this user on this start_hour to end_hour, falling under this timeslot.

Comment: It is important to say that a timeslot may have multiple appointments. Its more like availability. I was trying to find a suitable word. I have a timeslot avaiabilty from 10 to 11h and I may have 10:00-10:15 and 10:30-11:00 as appointments.

But that makes sense, I dont necessarily need to have the information of which timeslot it was made...

Comment: @Luc, Now I understand it better. I have updated the answer